# Sending a file over a socket with Python only working after force-closing socket

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, sockets

I'm trying to send a file over a socket in Python 2.7.x . My client and server code is below. It's working, but only after the client connection kills the socket. So I added `raw_input('finished')` to the end of both for debugging.

So if I start the server, then run the client... It looks like all but the last bit of the file sends, until I forcefully kill the client and then it's all there. So the problem is definitely in the server loop... I just don't know how to fix it. `if not data: break` isn't being triggered. But, if I do something like `if len(data) < 1024: break` it won't work for bigger files.

Any help is appreciated!

```
# client.py

import socket

conn = socket.socket()
conn.connect(('localhost', 1337))

f = open('test.jpg', 'rb')
data = f.read(1024)
while data:
    conn.send(data)
    data = f.read(1024)
f.close()

raw_input('finished')
```

---

```
# server.py

import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('localhost', 1337))
s.listen(5)
conn, addr = s.accept()

f = open('test.jpg', 'wb')
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    f.write(data)
f.close()

raw_input('finished')
```

Comment: Seems to be working for me on a random set of files; perhaps it would help if you flushed the data being written on the client side.

Comment: @lungj Try a binary/image file larger than 1MB. It works for me with small plain text files. But even with small plain text files the server hangs and never finishes like it should.

Comment: I created a 4MB file containing random data using `dd if=/dev/urandom of=test_if.jpg count=4096  bs=1024`; still seems to work. I'm on Python 2.7.13 on macOS.

Comment: Hm, that size file seemed to all send correctly for me as well. But, the server still hangs... I never see the server hit `raw_input("finished")` as it should. It's stuck in the while loop.

Comment: Do you know which line the server hangs on? Oh... I just noticed you're not closing your socket on the client side -- you're only closing your input file. Perhaps that's the issue.

Answer (score 2):

From your posted code:

```
while data:
   conn.send(data)
   data = f.read(1024)
```

From the [Python socket documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html):

```
socket.send(string[, flags])
[...]
Returns the number of bytes sent. Applications are responsible for checking 
that all data has been sent; if only some of the data was transmitted, the 
application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data.
```

That should tell you what the problem is, but just to be explicit about it:  send() may or may not accept all of the bytes you asked it to send before returning, and it's up to you to handle it correctly in the case where it only accepts the first (n) bytes rather than the entire buffer.  If you don't check send()'s return value, then you will sometimes drop some of the bytes of your file without knowing it.  You need to check send()'s return value and if it is less than len(data), call send() again (as many times as necessary) with the remaining bytes.  Alternatively you could call conn.sendall() instead of conn.send(), since sendall() will perform that logic for you.